# Black filled \lhd

Tags: symbols

I am looking for a symbol which exactly looks like `\lhd`, except that the inner is filled.

Note: We have`\blacktriangleleft`, but the shape is different.

I used detexify, but didn't find a suitable symbol.

Comment: Maybe you can use `\triangleleft` instead of `\lhd` to match the filled version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `amssymb`, `\lhd` and `\blacktriangleleft` have the same shape.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

${\lhd}{\blacktriangleleft}$

${\blacktriangleleft}{\lhd}$

\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}${\lhd}$}%
${\blacktriangleleft}$
\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}${\blacktriangleleft}$}%
${\lhd}$

\makebox[0pt][l]{${\lhd}$}%
\textcolor{red}{${\blacktriangleleft}$}
\makebox[0pt][l]{${\blacktriangleleft}$}%
\textcolor{red}{${\lhd}$}

\sbox0{$\lhd$}\the\wd0\ \the\ht0\ \the\dp0

\sbox0{$\blacktriangleleft$}\the\wd0\ \the\ht0\ \the\dp0

\end{document}
```

[image]

Remember, though, that `\lhd` is a binary operation symbol; if you want to use the glyph as a relation symbol, do something like

```
\newcommand{\lhdrel}{\mathrel\lhd}
```

and use `\lhdrel` (any name is good, of course).

Comment: I have a complicated document with lots of packages, only after adding the package `amsfonts`, the size and the shape of  `\lhd` and `\blacktriangleleft ` became the same.

Comment: @Name That's what MWE (minimal examples that reproduce the issue) are recommended when you ask a question.